# sage pay paypal example

Tags: magento, paypal

we currently use magento shopping cart and sagepay via ebizmarts plugin and paypal standard payments but we are thinking about using paypal through sage pay.

Does paypal still have its own button in magento or can the customer only select paypal once they are in sage pay.

We seem to get a lot of connection problems from magento to paypal with failed transactions and orders not being updated with the correct payment status.

Our thinking is that if we let sage handle the communications this will reduce the number of failed/error transactions.

But we do want it to remain obvious to the customer that we accept paypal
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal via SagePay can be integrated via FORM or SERVER integration with full redirection or, customer can choose PayPal on checkout or customer can click on the quick checkout button in the cart page.

Keep in mind that PayPal via Sage Pay is only available on Sage Pay Suite PRO, not Sage Pay Suite Community Edition.

If you have further questions, please don't hesitate on contacting us [here](http://ebizmarts.com/contact-us).

Kind Regards,
Pablo